# How could I insert 2 borders in one Grid with c# code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I try to get two borders in one grid with c# code.
I have one Grid in xaml that looks like this:

```
<Grid Name="GridKalkAuswahl" ShowGridLines="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="463">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="38px"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="16px"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40px"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Now I want to insert two Borders into the Grid.

```
Border myborder = new Border();
myborder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
myborder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
GridKalkAuswahl.Children.Add(myborder);
Grid.SetRowSpan(myborder, noStaffel.Count);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(myborder, 4);
```

But this ist just one Border. How could i get a second one into the Grid? If I do that the same way the 2 Border are on the same place.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Where do you expect the borders to be?

Comment: @Anka, can you please give any feedback to the answers you received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set Margin to inner border. make that Margin equal to outer border Thickness

```
Border myborder = new Border
{
    BorderBrush = Brushes.DarkGray,
    BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
};
GridKalkAuswahl.Children.Add(myborder);
Grid.SetRowSpan(myborder, noStaffel.Count);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(myborder, 4);

Border myborder2 = new Border
{
    BorderBrush = Brushes.Orange,
    BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
    Margin = myborder.BorderThickness
};
GridKalkAuswahl.Children.Add(myborder2);
Grid.SetRowSpan(myborder2, noStaffel.Count);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(myborder2, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

"But this ist just one Border. How could i get a second one into the Grid? If I do that the same way the 2 Border are on the same place."  Ofcourse they're on the same place. Everything works as expected with your code. If you will create two borders, add them to the grid as it's children it's fine but if you will set the same columnspan and rowspan they will simply be on the same place. Please take a look at the example below:

```
        Border myborder = new Border();
        myborder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
        myborder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
        GridKalkAuswahl.Children.Add(myborder);
        Grid.SetRowSpan(myborder, 1);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(myborder, 4);

        Border myborder2 = new Border();
        myborder2.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Crimson);
        myborder2.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
        GridKalkAuswahl.Children.Add(myborder2);
        Grid.SetRowSpan(myborder2, 1);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(myborder2, 3);
```

**Grid.SetColumnSpan** and **Grid.SetRowSpan** is the key to your problem.